# Apple Watch OS 2 how to show/ hide action button from custom notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am building a an apple watch os 2 app extension and I need to implement notifications. As I read the apple docs I sow that what I need is an custom notification, so have build the UI for it, but the thing is that I have to handle multiple notifications cases and not all of them have one action button, so my question is how do change the name of an action button and if it possible to hide it.

I know that the action buttons can be created using the PushNotificationPayload.apns file and also in the apns file you set up the action button and function, but is it possible to also do this in code(hide/ show button action and also adjust it's name).

I was thinking that I could do some implementation in didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletion:?

And here is some background info:

[image]
[image]

## Update 1

After reading again this apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html) I made the next changes:

1. Implemented another Notification Interface Controller and checked the "Has Dynamic Interface"

[image]

2. Added "Notification Category Name"

[image]

3. Created another subclass of the "WKUserNotificationInterfaceController" and associated it with the new custom notification in storyboard

Managed to test that the correct Categorry is loaded when the notification arrives using the "category" key and the correct value for each custom category, in my case "Cat1" and "Cat2".

And now the only question that I have is:

**How do I manage the custom notifications button locally?(how many buttons are displayed, the title of the buttons, so that I am not depending on the server as in the .apns test notification)**

If this is not possible then my question becomes:

**How should the notification from server look like(the format) regarding the actions that are displayed?** should I still send the actions as:

```
"WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
        {
            "title": "First Button",
            "identifier": "firstButtonAction"
        }
    ]
```

or should I pass them in the `aps` key as:

```
"alert" : {
     "body" : "Test message",
     "title" : "Optional title",
     "action" : [
        {
           "title" : "First Button",
           "identifier" : "firstButtonAction"
        }
     ]
  }
```

## Update 2

After reading the documentation for [Adding Action Buttons to Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html) I think that this is what I need to do, also read this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/).
But the main difference is that by doing so it will also affect my iOS app and I want the action button only for the notifications that I retrieve on my watch, is this possible to add actions in the app delegate on the IOS app and only affect the look of the notifications on my watch app?

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: Any update regarding having the action on the Watch only?